# Run docker compose without sudo

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using `docker` and `docker compose` for my python web application. Everything was running smooth, but few days back, I am unable to `build and up` custom and standard images.

- I reinstalled the version I was using but failed (docker-compose) # from ubuntu repository using apt
- I updated to the latest version but still failed (docker compose) # offical site using apt

I have added the user to docker group.
I checked `docker compose config` working correctly as values properly substituted.
Below is my code:

```
# File: .env

# General settings
PROJECT_NAME=titanic
```

```
# File: docker-compose.yml

version: "3.7"

services:
  redis:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_redis_container
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: redis/Dockerfile
      args:
        - REDIS_IMG=${REDIS_IMG}
    image: ${PROJECT_NAME}_redis_image
    # restart: always
    ports:
     - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - internal_network
    user: redis
    volumes:
      - redis_volume:/data  
      
      
volumes:
  redis_volume:
    name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_redis_volume
```

I am getting following error as below:

```
invalid tag "\"titanic\"_redis_image": invalid reference format
```

I am using `MakeFile` to create my project, I run just `make`

```
.PHONY: all
all: dc-build dc-up
    @echo "Process finished..."
    
.PHONY: dc-build
dc-build:
    @echo "Building all images..."
    docker compose build

.PHONY: dc-up
dc-up:
    @echo "Launching all services..."
    docker compose up
```

More strange is that if I use `sudo` infornt of docker compose command, it runs successfully with both
my previous docker and docker-compose version and also with the latest one.

Added: I am needing `sudo` to run from/Via `MakeFile`. If I run(docker-compose build or up --build) directly on terminal it works.

I am unable to figure out the cause, what I am missing?

Comment: Maybe try to change the line(s) in your Dockerfile to this: `image: "webapp:${PROJECT_FILE}_redis_image"`.  Putting the value inside a quoted string.

Comment: Hi sjking, Thanks. I already tried that also but it did not worked eg `image: "${PROJECT_NAME}_redis_image"`

Comment: Is something setting the `PROJECT_NAME` environment variable, maybe elsewhere in your `Makefile` or in your host environment?  `sudo` generally resets the environment and that could explain the difference.

Comment: The Docker documentation explains exactly how to remove the need for sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other comments and answers are suggesting a problem around the `$PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.  Your Compose file uses it in three places, but you don't need any of these.  If you just delete these three lines you can avoid the substitution and quoting problems you're describing.

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    # container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_redis_container  <-- delete
    build: { ... }
    # image: ${PROJECT_NAME}_redis_image               <-- delete
volumes:
  redis_volume:
    # name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_redis_volume               <-- delete
```

You're asking Compose to do three things on your behalf here: build an image, create a named volume, and start a container.  For all three of these things, Compose can pick its own name, and you don't need to override these in most cases.  If the variable substitution here is causing a problem, just deleting the lines that use it should solve it.

It turns out that the default Compose names are very similar to what you're showing in any case.  Compose has its own notion of a "project name" – [`$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_project_name), defaulting to the base name of the current directory – and when Compose generates names it includes this project name at the start of its names.  If the current directory is named `titanic`, then on its own Compose will create an image named `titanic_redis`, a volume named `titanic_redis_volume`, and a container named `titanic_redis_1`.  That's pretty close to what you are trying to specify by hand.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. I was about to comment all the required lines as you mentioned. But on reading your above comment for `makefile` solved the issue. My bad, in the `makefile` for `echo` purpose I was displaying the project name with same variable as `PROJECT_NAME := "titanic"` after renaming this to other name `docker-compose` is working without `sudo`. I thought that variable is local to `makefile` but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error `invalid tag "\"titanic\"_redis_image": invalid reference format`
Images are identified by image references, which can be a repository name or a image hash. So it is telling you that the string you are providing to `image:` is wrong.

That looks like this:

```yaml
    image: ${PROJECT_NAME}_redis_image
```

So by doing a reverse substitution, we can see that `PROJECT_NAME` is set to `"\"titanic\""` which does not a valid path, or image repository reference, make.

Don't double escape your strings. If this double escaped string has not somehow polluted your environment, then it seems a bug has been introduced in compose, and this is worth a bug report. But the fact it works with sudo implies it works fine when given a clean environment.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks. I am not adding any double quotes but still it seems somehow getting added but earlier it was not the case, same `docker-compose.yml` file was working smoothly. Also, `sudo` does not seems permanent solution.